# Is there way to add and subtract the number of days in dates in impala

Tags: sql, impala

I have requirement where table A is having the cont_number,start_dates and end_dates and
table B is having cont_number,numberofdays(numbers of days having + and - values eg:30,-20)
Table A:

| cont_number | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 276820 | 01-Jul-2021 | 31-Jul-2021 |
| 817689 | 01-Jun-2021 | 30-Jun-2021 |
| 827628 | 01-Sep-2021 | 30-sep-2021 |

Table-B

| cont_number | Numberofdays |
| --- | --- |
| 276820 | -30 |
| 817689 | 40 |
| 827628 | 20 |

**If Table B Numberofdays having +ve value it should add those days to end_date of Table-A and if it is -ve value then it should add to start_date
Please help me with this below requirement**

Expecting output:

| cont_number | start_date | end_date | new_start_date | new_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 276820 | 01-Jul-2021 | 31-Jul-2021 | 01-Jun-2021 | 31-Jul-2021 |
| 817689 | 01-Jun-2021 | 30-Jun-2021 | 01-Jun-2021 | 09-Aug-2021 |
| 827628 | 01-Sep-2021 | 30-sep-2021 | 01-Sep-2021 | 20-Oct-2021 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `if` or `case-when` in impala.

```
select 
a.cont_number cont_number,
a.start_date,
a.end_date,
if (b.Numberofdays>= 0 then a.end_date+ interval b.Numberofdays days,a.start_date) new_start_date,
if (b.Numberofdays< 0 then a.start_date+ interval b.Numberofdays days,a.end_date) new_end_date
from tablea A, tableb B
where a.cont_number=b.cont_number
```

new_start_date is calculated as if Numberofdays >=0 then end_date + Numberofdays else use original start date.
new_end_date is calculated as if Numberofdays <0 then start_date + Numberofdays else use original end date.